# Get jQuery drag 'n' drop script to update ANOTHER list

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, draggable, droppable

I have almost succeeded, with help from the stackoverflow community, in coding a jQuery drag-n-drop "add to/remove from favorites" site.

At the front end, two lists of movies appear, on the one side those which the user has favorited and on the other those which are not in the user's list of favorites. You can drag titles to a drop box to add/delete them from one list and put them in the other. This updates a MySQL database in the background, and when a title has been dragged out of a list it disappears from that list, as desired.

Only one thing still does not work - the front-end addition of the movie title to the list it is being dragged INTO - this needs a page refresh to show the updated result.

I see the problem - the two jQuery scripts don't know what the other is doing - each one REMOVES the item dragged from its own list with no problem, but how to tell each script to ADD to the OTHER list, I do not know.

I tried using connectWith but got confused....

HTML (movies list):

```
<div class="content_box2 content_box_drag2" onMouseOver="drag_two();">
    (PHP-generated list of all available movies)
</div>

<div class="content_box_drop content_holder_box">
    <p class="dropper">Drop movie title here to remove from favourites</p>
</div>
```

HTML (favorites list):

```
<div class="content_box content_box_drag" onMouseOver="drag();">
    (PHP-generated list of favourite movies)
</div>

<div class="content_holder_box2 content_box_drop2">
    <p class="dropper2">Drop movie title here to add to favourites</p>
</div>
```

Script to REMOVE a movie from favorites:

```
var user_id = "<?php Print($user_id); ?>";

function drag(){

    $( ".content_box_drag p" ).draggable({
        appendTo: "body",
        helper: "clone",
        revert: "invalid",
    });

    $( ".content_box_drop p" ).droppable({
        activeClass: "dropper_hover",
        hoverClass: "dropper_hover",
        accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
        var parent = $(".dragelement:last"); // KEEP THIS!
        var movie_id = parent.attr('id');    // KEEP THIS!              
           $.ajax({
               url: "php-includes/delete_favs.inc.php",
               type: "GET",
               data: { movie_id: movie_id, user_id: user_id },
               success:function(data){
                   $('#'+movie_id).remove();
               }
           });
        }
    });
}
```

Almost identical script to ADD a movie to favorites:

```
var user_id = "<?php Print($user_id); ?>";

function drag_two(){

    $( ".content_box_drag2 p" ).draggable({
        appendTo: "body",
        helper: "clone",
        revert: "invalid",
    });

    $( ".content_box_drop2 p" ).droppable({
        activeClass: "dropper_hover2",
        hoverClass: "dropper_hover2",
        accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
        var parent = $(".dragelement:last"); // KEEP THIS!
        var movie_id = parent.attr('id');    // KEEP THIS!              
           $.ajax({
               url: "php-includes/add_favs.inc.php",
               type: "GET",
               data: { movie_id: movie_id, user_id: user_id },
               success:function(data){
                   $('#'+movie_id).remove();
               }
           });
        }
    });

}
```

Any help again very much appreciated!

Comment: Create a simple example in http://jsfiddle.net or http://tinkerbin.com/ so someone can help troubleshoot the issue. Your post is a wall of text!

Comment: I've tried but can't get it to work on either site. I didn't think the code was too hard to understand - the HTML is very simple and the key part of the scripts is what happens in the `success` clause: `$('#'+movie_id).remove();` deletes an item from its own list in each case but I need something which will add an item to the other side as well, without a page refresh.